# How would I make this query return all rows with the id of 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay, so excuse me if this is a silly question but I'm not all too familiar with MYSQL.

Here we go:

When you perform the following code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM blogfeed WHERE id = 1");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
return $result;
```

it returns an array with all the information in the row where the id = 1.

Now, just for example let's say there is more than 1 row with the id of 1.
How would I make the query return an array with all of those rows?
Currently, it is only returning one of the rows and there are 2 of them.

Comment: I don't get it. If in the table there's more than one row from id = 1 (and this is wrong because id must be unique), the count of the array returned must be > 1. check the db and the query filter

Comment: `id` is not a reserved column in MySQL. It does not have to be `UNIQUE` (although the name implies that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mres = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM blogfeed WHERE id = 1");
$results = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mres)) {
    $results[] = $result;
}
return $results;
```